# Oracle Apex-Color specific Interactive grids cells based on position

Tags: css, oracle-apex

I need help with css styling of interactive grid.

In my requirement, the rows of grid are fixed. In the rows some cells are blue/some grey and so on.

In this case what css style/js can be used to point to a particular cell at particular index in ig and use colors?

So, in short the requirement is different colors for different cells for fixed rows IG.
Oracle Apex-20.2
Ex:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do the grid cells need to be editable?  If not you can do this:

1. Add columns based on CASE expressions to define CSS classes for particular values e.g.

   case col1 when 'C' then 'class1'
   when 'H' then 'class2'
   ...
   end as col1_class
2. Change the column type to `HTML Expression`
3. Set the column's HTML Expression property to:

   `<div class="&COL1_CLASS.">&COL1.</div>`
4. Set up CSS to define the classes - e.g. in the page inline CSS:

   .class1 {background-color: #fd0}
   .class2 {background-color: #aaa}
   ...

Here is an example where I have done this to highlight the job MANAGER in red:

[image]

You can add further CSS to remove padding from the cells, add padding to your `div`s etc.

Comment: White ones editable, rest all will be locked.

Comment: This probably doesn't help you then.

Comment: You can't edit a target of HTML type, why didn't those ORACLE pataphiles make CSS CLASSES option to accept values from another column?